# Appending a string to a json parse returns a string literal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some currencies i have saved inside the state manager of my app and this is how i am calling it:

For instance, to get the value of Euro against dollar, i

```
JSON.parse(this.$store.state.clientSide.currencyrates).rates.EURO
```

I am getting the currency from a click event and once i acquire the currency symbol, i am passing it to the statement above to fetch me the exchange rate

```
let currency = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('currency');
let new_currency = currency.toUpperCase();
var state_fx = JSON.parse(this.$store.state.clientSide.currencyrates).rates.`${new_currency}`;
this.$store.commit('setCurrency', new_currency);
alert('state fx'+state_fx);
```

i was expecting `alert()` to show me the numeric value of the exchange rate but instead i get a long string of `JSON.parse(this.$store.state.clientSide.currencyrates).rates.INR` when i try getting the rupee exchange rate.

Doing this

```
var state_fx = "JSON.parse(this.$store.state.clientSide.currencyrates).rates."+new_currency;
```

produces same result. How can i pass the currency symbol safely so that i return the exchange rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`bracket-notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```
JSON.parse(this.$store.state.clientSide.currencyrates).rates[new_currency]
```